# Adding items to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, navigation, drawer

I am created a To Do List application for Android and have thus far implemented an action bar with a '+' button which causes a popup to appear where the user enters the name of a list they wish to create and it is then added to the ListView which displays the text.

What I am looking for is the ability to click on each list item and be taken to a new blank page, where the user can repeat the process but add list items, rather than actual lists. From here, they could use a Navigation Drawer to easily switch between Lists. **How can I make it so that the navigation drawer shows the lists added on the first page?**

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the Android Developer Guide for Creating a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)?
Once you create the drawer, you treat it as a listview add items in the same way as you would to a listview. Is there a specific issue that you are encountering with the navigation drawer?

UPDATE:

This was retrieved from [Google's documentation on Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). There is a project you can download from here and I would highly suggest doing so.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String[] mPlanetTitles;
private ListView mDrawerList;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    ...
}
}
```

Comment: So if I implement a Navigation Drawer, when I click on the '+' in my application, and create a new list which is displayed in a listview, it will automatically be added to the navigation drawer once its pulled out from the left?

Comment: You wont want to create a new list necessarily, but add to the list that the navigation drawer is already using.

Comment: How can I point the navigation drawer to read the data contained within the ListView?

Comment: I have edited the code, I highly suggest downloading the sample project. You will find there is a full implementation of the navigation drawer.